# Hide ribbon except attach file

Tags: ribbon

I would like to know whether there is any way to hide ribbon except attach file icon. I have tried this

```
document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "none";
```

but this will hide the whole ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify `id` for individual items and then can do something like:

```
#Ribbon.ListItem.New{
    display:none;
}
```